# Post Category link is same with Page link

Tags: posts, categories, pages, links, title

Right now, our posts category is displayed as: /[category-name]. So when we have a post category named "Matcha" and a page named "Matcha", they have the same links and http://sitename.com/matcha displays the post category instead of the page.

Is there a way to change the post category link to this /category/[category-name] to avoid conflict with pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a custom link structure in the [Permalink Settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen).

There is a field for 'category base' name.